# pgModeler installation - Dependencies error

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install the pgModeler. But I'm getting stuck.

I have pgModeler at /opt/pgmodeler-0.5.2/

I have all the dependencies: Qt 5.0, Pg and the others.

When I run the pgmodeler with ./pgmodeler, this error occurs:

```
./pgmodeler: error while loading shared libraries: libutils.so.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

For me the error is clear. Executing

```
$ ldd pgmodeler
```

the full stack of dependencies is shown. But in this part some files were not found.

```
libutils.so.1 => not found
libparsers.so.1 => not found
libdbconnect.so.1 => not found
libobjrenderer.so.1 => not found
libpgmodeler.so.1 => not found
libpgmodeler_ui.so.1 => not found
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => not found
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

I have all of these files. But I don't know how to set for pgmodeler find it. I created a file under /etc/profile.d/, called pgmodeler.sh, like the pgmodeler.vars suggest. No way! Still the problem occurs.

Tried to add to PATH variable the paths of the dependecies, copy the files to the directory...

Well. Nothing. :(

Someone can help me? If need more information, I can bring it readily. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an update on the documentation, try with this script, adapting to your installation path.

```
#/bin/bash

# Specify here the full path to the pgmodeler's root directory
export PGMODELER_ROOT="/path/to/pgmodeler"

export PGMODELER_CONF_DIR="$PGMODELER_ROOT/conf"
export PGMODELER_SCHEMAS_DIR="$PGMODELER_ROOT/schemas"
export PGMODELER_LANG_DIR="$PGMODELER_ROOT/lang"
export PGMODELER_TMP_DIR="$PGMODELER_ROOT/tmp"
export PGMODELER_PLUGINS_DIR="$PGMODELER_ROOT/plugins"
export PGMODELER_CHANDLER_PATH="$PGMODELER_ROOT/pgmodeler-ch"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$PGMODELER_ROOT"
export PATH=$PATH:$PGMODELER_ROOT

#Running pgModeler
pgmodeler
```

Here's the full article: http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/wiki/doku.php?id=installation

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you've downloaded a 32-bit version on a 64-bit system or vice versa.  You can run 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system *if* you install 32-bit libraries, but since there is a 64-bit pgModeler, that's kind of silly.

I'm presuming by:

> I have all the dependencies

You mean that you installed them via ubuntu and not yourself, in which case there might be a problem for the linker.

It should not be a matter of configuring pgModeler; if the libraries are installed properly, then the linker will find them, pgModeler does not need to know where they are.  If they are not installed properly, letting pgModeler know where they are is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `PATH=$PATH:$PGMODELER_ROOT`?

If so, try to add:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$PGMODELER_ROOT"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib
```

to `/etc/profile`. If you have Qt5 Installed.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, for me work perfectly to add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$PGMODELER_ROOT"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib
```

to /etc/profile. If you have Qt5 Installed.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

1. rename the file `pgmodeler.vars`

   ```
   $ mv pgmodeler.vars pgmodeler.sh
   ```
2. modify a line of `pgmodeler.sh` file with the path of `pgmodeler`

   ```
   # Specify here the full path to the pgmodeler's root directory
   export PGMODELER_ROOT="/path/to/pgmodeler"
   ```
3. save the file and source:

   ```
   source pgmodeler.sh
   ```
4. finally execute:

   ```
   ./pgmodeler
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, late to the party, but I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by changing the `start-pgmodeler.sh` file referenced in the documentation to include the correct path to the lib file.  Some of the answers above reference the QT lib file.  That may also work, but what worked for me was changing this line to include `/lib` in the `start-pgmodeler.sh` file.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$PGMODELER_ROOT/lib"
```